# Why does git assign same hash to files with different names and location?

Tags: git, git-hash

Why does git assign the same `SHA-1` to files with different names and different locations although contents is the same?

`100644 43efcd84207788e5289ee23a9ce95d9f43b13d9a 0       dir1/dir1_d2/dir1_d2_f1.txt
100644 43efcd84207788e5289ee23a9ce95d9f43b13d9a 0       test.txt`

Show file contents:

`$ git cat-file -p 43efcd84207788e5289ee23a9ce95d9f43b13d9a
Line 1`

Thanks

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Because** content is the same!

Git tracks content in blob object.
Paths are resolved by git with tree objects.

You can read [Pro Git - Git Internals - Git Objects](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) to know how git store data.

Comment: Does git performs a comparison of __Each__ file's content with __Each__ file in the cache/staging area and upon matching adds a new entry in the index with the same hash (reference to same object) as that of the original file and its corresponding name to that of newly tracked file?

Comment: No, for any new object to store, git simply hash it, then if the hash already exists the object is already stored, else it's a new object to store.